# RXjs 7 : cannot read property ''findUser' of undefined

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, rxjs-observables

After updating rxjs 6 to rxjs 7 it's showing cannor read property 'findUser' of undefined

```
const {blCustomer, plCustomer}= await this.client.getClient().findUser({userId:id}).topromise()
```

How to convert this into rxjs 7 compatible

Comment: There aren't enough details here. What does any of this code do? What does getClient() return?

Comment: true, there aren't enough details, please show us what `this.client` ist and `getClient()`, but it looks like that `getClient()` is returning `undefined`